# jQuery top scroll animation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do the animation as http://virrecsgo.com/ when you scroll, and the top has this loading function keeping track on how far you've scrolled.

I've tried different things, such as

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                if (scroll >= 1) {
                    $("nav").addClass("one");
                }
            });
```

But that's not effective at all. Is there any script for this or is there any algorithm so I can make it more simple?

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, you can do:

```
$("html, body").animate({ 
    scrollTop: 0 //Zero, considering its the absolute top of your page
}, 1000);
```